# Magento 1.9.2.2 - Custom Module 404 Error

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller, routes

This is my first go with Magento and I've been trying to figure out how to create a custom module. When I attempt to view my module, I am getting a 404 error... so, here's what I have.

### app/etc/modules/Levan_Mymodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
<modules>
    <Levan_Mymodule>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Levan_Mymodule>
</modules>
```

### app/code/local/Levan/Mymodule/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Levan_Mymodule>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Levan_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <Mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Levan_Mymodule</module>
                    <frontname>Mymodule</frontname>
                </args>
            </Mymodule>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

### app/code/local/Levan/Mymodule/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Levan_Mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        echo "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Attempting to view my page at

magentoserver.com/index.php/Mymodule/index

Just returns a 404 Error. Any thoughts?

**edit**

Cache is indeed disabled. var/cache folder was removed. No luck.

Comment: Apparently, using <frontname> is wrong. It's <frontName>.

Answer (score 0):

This is Tested solution :

**You made two mistakes :**

First Mistake in below file :

**app/etc/modules/Levan_Mymodule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <config>
        <modules>
            <Levan_Mymodule>
              <active>true</active>
              <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Levan_Mymodule>
        </modules>
     </config>
```

**Mistake :**  Closing tag is missing `</config>`

Second Mistake On below file :

**app/code/local/Levan/Mymodule/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
      <modules>
        <Levan_Mymodule>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Levan_Mymodule>
      </modules>
     <frontend>
        <routers>
          <mymodule>
            <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                <module>Levan_Mymodule</module>
                <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
              </args>
          </mymodule>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

This tag should be in small letters `<mymodule>`

Check and let me know if you still have any Issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a magento problem that if any extension is installed, we have to clear cache or sign out backend first, otherwise it will show you error like 404 Error or Page not found.

So whenever you installed a new plugin in magento, please sign out backend or clear cache.